# PHP DOM How to remove wrapping tags when children contain tags and text nodes

Tags: php, dom

Given this markup

```
<badtag>
  This is the title and <em>really</em> needs help
<badtag>
```

I need to remove the  wrapper, but do it without losing the  tag, which is what happens if I simply do something like:

```
dom->createTextNode(currentNode->nodeValue)
```

I've tried the following, but it's not quite working and I want to make sure I'm on the right track and not missing an easier way. I do note that I need to add iteration when I hit a tag in the switch statement (rather than #text) so that I get the contents of the tag (such as with the  tag).

```
      $l = $origElement->childNodes->length;
      $new = [];
      for ($i = 0; $i < $l; ++$i) {
        $child = $origElement->childNodes->item($i);
        switch ($child->nodeName) {
          case '#text':
            $new[] = $dom->createTextNode($origElement->textContent);
            break;
          default:
            $new[] = $child;
            break;
        }
      }
      foreach ($new as $struct) {
        $parentNode->insertBefore($struct, $origElement);
      }
      $origElement->parentNode->removeChild($origElement);
```

Comment: It will help if you put a full example of the code

Comment: that is the full example other than the function header, and 1500+ lines of other dom- and xml- related transformation class that isn't related to the issue.

Comment: *I need to remove the wrapper, but do it without losing the tag*...from posted snippet, what is the wrapper and what is the tag?

Comment: *and 1500+ lines of other dom- and xml- related transformation class* ... I hope you know what XSLT is (the dedicated XML transformation language) as you can cut down on a lot of `for` loops and `if`/`switch` logic. See [php/xsl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xsl.php). Certainly for this question!

Comment: The wrapper is the badtag tag. The tag I don't want to lose is the em within it.

Comment: Yup, know what XSLT is. XSLT works great with just XML, but the code is producing HTML markup (XSLT doesn't care much about presentation, just structure) and deals with things like Oasis tables and MathML.

Comment: XSLT can absolutely produce HTML, even csv/txt/json. See [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt/info). And XSLT is a stylesheet language akin to CSS, so of course it cares about presentation. Provide a fuller example so I can show you as removing *badtag* leaves a not well-formed document (i.e., no root).

Comment: The answer given, below, solves my immediate issue. In terms of an example, <mathml:msup><mathml:mi>C</mathml:mi><mathml:mm>2</mathml:mm></mathml:sup> needing to be C<sup>2</sup> is an example of, in part, dropping the wrapping tags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've created something which creates a clone of the content of the node you want to remove.  It didn't seem to like just moving the nodes, and when I use `cloneNode` instead, the new version seemed a lot cleaner.

```
<?php
error_reporting ( E_ALL );
ini_set ( 'display_errors', 1 );

$xml = <<<EOB
<DATA>
<badtag>
  This is the title and <em>really</em> needs help
</badtag>
</DATA>
EOB;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xml);

$origElement = $dom->getElementsByTagName("badtag")[0];
$newParent = $origElement->parentNode;
foreach ( $origElement->childNodes as $child ){
    $newParent->insertBefore($child->cloneNode(true), $origElement);
}
$newParent->removeChild($origElement);
echo $dom->saveXML();
```

For the small sample I've used, the output is...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<DATA>

  This is the title and <em>really</em> needs help

</DATA>
```